# Watching animes for fun

Tags: halal-haram, cartoon

I am really confused.You might have heard of pokemon.I know that it is just a fictional story and just for entertainment.i know that we can do our entertainment until and unless it diverts us from worship of Allah.Some say that pokemon promotes gambling .I don't understand these all things.I mean it is just a fictional story and it does not even contain something really sexual.So pls tell me whether:
1.Watching pokemon is Haram
2.Playing pokemon is Haram
Pls say me whether it is 'O.K','Not advisable ' or 'Haram' .Pls Explain

Answer (score 1):

Aslamu Walaykum

If the anime that you are watching does not include nudity, haram relationships, neither does it distract you from remembering Allah, and doing your chores. Then it is permissible to watch as long as it follows the conditions.